# WCF Soap webservice and authentication

Tags: wcf, authentication, soap, basichttpbinding

I am creating a WCF service which uses basicHttpBinding(SOAP).  I would like each request to the webservice to require an account name and a key, essentially a username and password.  Currently these values are being passed as arguments to each exposed method.  Is this the proper way to handle this situation?  It seems to violate DRY, and I'm guessing that there is an easier, built in way.  I have seen some examples of inserting a username and a password into the headers by intercepting the request but that approach seems to add quite a bit of effort for clients connecting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rather then sending the user name and password ever request, why not have a login method that returns a token, and pass that?

If you want to minimize DRY you can do the following:

First, make a generic class similar to the following that all request contracts inherit from (besides Login and Logout):

```
[MessageContract]
public abstract class AuthenticatedRequest <T> {
    [MessageHeader]
    public string Token { get; set;]
}
```

Now make a private function called `private bool IsAuthenticated(string Token)` that checks the token. This minimizes the ceremony of checking for authentication.

Comment: Hi Justin, sorry for the delay.  Would I need to call this "IsAuthenticated" method from every webservice method?  Is there anything inherently wrong with passing a username/password with each request?  It seems like the easiest way for the client as well.  Currently i'm looking at a webservice with only a few exposed methods.

Comment: If you pass a token you have a concept of a session, which might be good for tracking purposes. Generally if you can reduce the amount of times you transmit the username and password with a temporary proxy for them (said token) its a little more secure.